# QTableView & QDelegate -- QTextEdit opening on left corner

Tags: qt, qtableview

I am working on `QTableview` inside a `QStandardItemModel`. I am using `QTextEdit` inside a class derived from `Qdeligates`. This allows me to insert newline inside tableview.

Most of the things are working fine but now i am facing a challenge that when ever i click a cell to edit `QTextEdit` is opening on the left corner of the GUI. When I click cell `row 0, column 3` text edit opens on the left corner.

How can i make my `QTextEdit` to open near the cell which i am editing `?`
Also what should i put inside this function `updateEditorGeometry` ?

Here is my initialising code for tableview :--

```
ui->testCaseTableView->verticalHeader()->resizeSections(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);  //---> original
ui->testCaseTableView->verticalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->testCaseTableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

//Set model & deligate
ui->testCaseTableView->setModel(model);
ui->testCaseTableView->setItemDelegate(mydeligate);
```

Here is my code for the deligate :---

```
QWidget* textViewDeligate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{

    QTextEdit *tableEdit = new QTextEdit(parent);
    return tableEdit;
}

void textViewDeligate::setEditorData ( QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex & index ) const
{

    QString value = index.model()->data(index,Qt::EditRole).toString();

    QTextEdit *tableEditCopy = static_cast<QTextEdit*>(editor);
    tableEditCopy->setPlainText(value);
}

void    textViewDeligate::setModelData ( QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    QTextEdit *tableEditCopy = static_cast<QTextEdit*>(editor);
    QString str = tableEditCopy->toPlainText();

    model->setData(index, str, Qt::EditRole);

}

void    textViewDeligate::updateEditorGeometry ( QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
{

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup the editor geometry of all widgets you create yourself. This is so that the widgets get given the correct dimensions of the tables' cells.

```
void    textViewDeligate::updateEditorGeometry ( QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was what improved it further :---

```
editor->setGeometry(option.rect.x(),option.rect.y(),editor->sizeHint().width(),editor->sizeHint().height());
```